# prove that $BPP(\alpha(n), \beta(n)) = BPP$

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, randomized-algorithms

prove that for every $0 \le \alpha(n), \beta(n) \le1 \; s.t.$ there exists $c \in \Bbb{N} \;s.t \;\alpha(n)+\beta(n) \le 1- \frac{1}{n^c}$ then $BPP(\alpha(n), \beta(n)) = BPP$.

I tried to show that by running k times we can get the error to be exponentially small using the chernoff inequality, for $0\le\delta\le1$
$$p(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \gt (1+\delta)pn) \le e^{-\delta^2pn} $$

If we run the algorithm k times, and accept only if we accepted at least $\frac{a(n)+b(n)}{2} k$ times.

then we should set $\delta = \frac{\alpha(n) + \beta(n)}{2\alpha(n)} -1$

But then I get stuck because it doesnt necessarily hold that $0 \le\delta \le 1$

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $\mathsf{BPP}(\alpha(n),\beta(n))$? The usual convention is that when the answer is 0, the input is accepted with probability at most $\alpha(n)$, and when it is 1, then the input is accepted with probability at least $\beta(n)$. But then the condition $\alpha(n) + \beta(n) \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n^c}$ makes no sense.

Comment: $BPP(\alpha(n),\beta(n)$ means that when the answer is 0, the input is accepted with probability at most $\alpha(n)$, and when it is 1, then the input is accepted with probability at least $1-\beta(n)$

Comment: Then it seems you might be using the wrong value for $\delta$. It should be $1-\beta(n)$ rather than $\beta(n)$.

Comment: Do you mean I should accept only if we accepted at least $\frac{\alpha(n) + 1 - \beta(n)}{2} k$ times, and set $\delta = \frac{\alpha(n) + 1 - \beta(n)}{2\alpha(n)} -1 $ ? But still how do I make sure the condition $0\le \delta\le 1$ holds?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus , forgot to tag you.

Comment: You should always have $\delta \geq 0$ (otherwise you're doing something wrong), and if $\delta > 1$, just use $\delta = 1$ instead, and you'll get a good enough bound.